# Here SDK mark position on map

Tags: android, sdk, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I show the user's position on the map but what I want to do is mark the same

In onCreate I get the position of the user:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get a MapView instance from layout


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        latitud=location.getLatitude();
        longitud=location.getLongitude();

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        handleAndroidPermissions();
    }
```

Then what I want to do when the map is loaded is to show it and put a mark, I do it as follows:

```
 private void loadMapScene() {
        // Load a scene from the SDK to render the map with a map style.
        mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapStyle.NORMAL_DAY, new MapScene.LoadSceneCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapScene.ErrorCode errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == null) {
                    mapObjectsExample = new MapObjectsExample(mapView);

                    GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates=new GeoCoordinates( latitud,longitud);

                    MapImage mapImage = MapImageFactory.fromResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.here_car);
                    MapMarker mapMarker = new MapMarker( geoCoordinates, mapImage);

                    mapView.getMapScene().addMapMarker(mapMarker);

                    mapView.getCamera().setTarget(new GeoCoordinates( latitud,longitud));
                    mapView.getCamera().setZoomLevel(15);

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onLoadScene failed: " + errorCode.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But I get:

> MapMarker(long, java.lang.Object)' has protected access in
> 'com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapMarker'

The problem is in this sentence:

```
                MapMarker mapMarker = new MapMarker( geoCoordinates, mapImage);
```

Comment: Can I see your class `MapMarker`

Comment: Not sure why you are attempting to cast to `long` - one `MapMarker` constructor takes `(Geocoordinates,MapImage)` as arguments which you have.  So just get rid of the `(long)` cast.  https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.7.0.0/api_reference/index.html

Comment: This is what I get if I take out cast: 'MapMarker(long, java.lang.Object)' has protected access in 'com.here.sdk.mapviewlite.MapMarker'

Comment: Interesting, so the `mapviewlite` is a key piece of information as it has a different api than `mapview`.  So, to add a marker use `MapMarker m = new MapMarker(geoCoordinates);` and to add the image use `m.addImage(mapImage, new MapMarkerImageStyle());` as an example.  It does not have the constructor you are attempting to use.  https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-lite/4.4.4.0/dev_guide/topics/map-items-lite.html#add-map-markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lite Product Variant we cannot pass the image Object directly to the MapMarker constructor.Below is the  code snippet how we use image marker in lite  Variant. The same is covered in the github example.

Github link: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/lite/android/MapMarkerLite

```
  MapImage mapImage = MapImageFactory.fromResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.here_car);

MapMarker mapMarker = new MapMarker(geoCoordinates);
mapMarker.addImage(mapImage, new MapMarkerImageStyle());

mapView.getMapScene().addMapMarker(mapMarker);
```